# how to get the energy input $U$ that gives the desired output $Y$?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, linear-regression

I have the I/O model

$$Y=HU$$

where $H$ is known. I want to design minimum input vector $U$ that gives a particular output $Y$.

Comment: What about $U = H^{-1}Y$? Is $H$ a matrix or a scalar? If matrix, is it square? What are the dimensions of $U,Y$ and $H$? Is $H$ invertible? What do you mean by "minimum input vector"? Please provide more information because right now it is not possible to give a meaningful answer because your question is not clear.

Comment: @SampleTime in optimization sense I am trying to solve $\begin{gathered}
  Arg\min \left\| U \right\|_2^2 \hfill \\
  s.t.Y = HU \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

Comment: @AlexMathy Sure, but what is $H$, $Y$ and $U$. Could you please describe clearly your variables here? Is $H$ a matrix? Please give the necessary details so that people can answer your question.

Comment: Y is a vector, H is a fat matrix, U is vector.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $H\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}^m$ where $n<<m$. I am also assuming that $H$ is full row rank.

The goal is to find $u$ such $y=Hu$ and $||u||_2^2$ is minimum. This is a constrained convex optimization problem which can be turned into the following unconstrained optimization problem with Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$:

$$\min_u J(u,\lambda)$$
where $J(u,\lambda):=u^Tu+\lambda^T(y-Hu)$.

Computing the derivative with respect to $u$ yields

$\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial u}=2u^T-\lambda^TH$.

One can verify that this is indeed a strict minimum since the Hessian $2I$ is positive definite. So, solving for the derivative to be 0, we get

$u^*=H^T\lambda^*/2$ where the superscript $*$ indicates optimality. Substituting this in the constraint $y=Hu^*$, we obtain $y=HH^T\lambda^*/2$, which yields

$$\lambda^*=2(HH^T)^{-1}y$$

and where $(HH^T)^{-1}$ exists because $H$ is full row rank by assumption. Using this expression, we obtain that

$$u^*=H^T(HH^T)^{-1}y.$$

Note that this solution coincides with the ordinary least-square solution where you want to minimize $(y-Hu)^T(y-Hu)$ where $H$ is full row rank

If the matrix $H$ is not full-row rank, then it is possible that there is no $u$ that satisfies $y=Hu$, and you will need to consider a slightly modified problem where you want to minimize the quantity

$$(y-Hu)^T(y-Hu)+\lambda u^Tu$$

where $\lambda>0$ is a regularization parameter. This leads to the so-called ridge regression.

Comment: why do you think it coincides with OLS solution ? don't you think it is counter-intuitive?

Comment: It coincides because there is a solution to the equation $y=Hu$. If there is no solution to the $y=Hu$, then the first problem is not feasible. Then, you have to go to the OLS solution assuming that $H$ is full row rank. If not, then Ridge regression. Also, note that those are standard problems and you should have looked a bit on the Internet by yourself before asking here. This can easily be found.

Comment: @AlexMathy Check https://courses.math.tufts.edu/math70/Section%20Summaries/Chapter6/sect%206.5.pdf for the least squares solution and compare with my expression for $u^*$.